# Delete message query using multiple join in table like gmail, is not correct

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have 3 tables:

1. **messages:**

   - sn
   - mfrom
   - mto
   - subject
   - message
   - mdate
   - mtime
2. **users:**

   - id
   - name
   - email
   - username
   - password
3. **user_message:**

   - id
   - sn
   - userid
   - flag

In these tables: for inbox and sent query is correct and it works, but in case of delete query it gives problems.

If we delete from message table it is inserted into user_message table updating flag value -1.

Now I need the correct query to display the messages of the trash or deleted items.

I have done this in core php. Please help me to fix the query:

```
 $query=" 
 select sn
      ,mfrom as address
      ,mfrom as io
      ,mto as address
      ,mto as io 
      ,message
      ,subject
      ,mdate
      ,mtime 
  from messages 
  join users 
    on users.id=messages.mto 
 where sn in(select sn from user_message where flag=-1 and userid=$id
)";
```

Comment: Post the queries you currently have that you have mentioned along with your application code to provide proper context.

Comment: $query=" select sn,mfrom as address,mfrom as io,mto as address,mto as io  ,message,subject,mdate,mtime
from messages inner join users on users.id=messages.mto where sn in(select sn from user_message where flag=-1 and userid=$id)"; 
 it works now...

Comment: i want to insert if it doesnt exist in user_message table and update if flag=1,0 to flag=-1 if deleted